# Convert XML to CSV using SAX Python

Tags: python, xml, sax

I have a XML file which has huge data size.

The XML file is containing

```
<us-bibliographic-data-grant>
    <publication-reference>
        <document-id>
            <country>US</country>
            <doc-number>D0607176</doc-number>
            <kind>S1</kind>
            <date>20100105</date>
        </document-id>
    </publication-reference>

    <application-reference appl-type="design">
        <document-id>
            <country>US</country>
            <doc-number>29327507</doc-number>
            <date>20081107</date>
        </document-id>
    </application-reference>

    <invention-title id="d0e55">Doughnut product with six appendages</invention-title>

    <applicants>
        <applicant sequence="001" app-type="applicant-inventor" designation="us-only">
            <addressbook>
            <last-name>Peters</last-name>
            <first-name>Brian Jeffery</first-name>
                <address>
                    <street>7052 Moonlight Cir.</street>
                    <city>Huntington Beach</city>
                    <state>CA</state>
                    <postcode>92647</postcode>
                    <country>US</country>
                </address>
            </addressbook>
            <nationality>
                <country>omitted</country>
            </nationality>
            <residence>
                <country>US</country>
            </residence>
        </applicant>
    </applicants>
</us-bibliographic-data-grant>
```

How can I get output like this

```
last-name,first-name,street,city,state,postcode,country
peters,brian jeffery, 7052 moonlight cir.,huntington beach,CA,92647
```

I have no experiences at all on XML, please help
In this XML code, there are many of `<addressbook>`. So how can I get all of the attributes inside the `applicant` in the first row, and the next rows are filled by all of the value. I want to do this because I want to import the csv file to sql later on.

Comment: This xml is not valid.

Comment: Why? I just copy the part of it tho, so many there are some startElements which have not endElements

Comment: Paste the XML [HERE](http://www.xmlvalidation.com) or some other validator. Try and run it through a parser. It is not valid or fully formed.

Comment: I have validated the code (which I edited before...) and it says "No errors were found"

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert from one file type to the other, you should use a tool.  Here's one suggestion -- https://code.google.com/p/xml2csv-conv/

I've used xslt in the past when I had complex xml documents to interpret.

Comment: I was asked to use Python for this. To convert only the address part... Pls help

Answer (score 0):

I am using BeautifulSoup for this, just replace your filename.xml with sample_1.xml in "string format "

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("sample_1.xml", encoding= 'UTF-8') as fp:
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'xml')
for a in soup.findAll("addressbook"):
    print(a.text)
```

Output:
Peters
Brian Jeffery
7052 Moonlight Cir.
Huntington Beach
CA
92647
US